# Xcode - Can't compile added framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, frameworks

I'm trying to use the [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) framework, So i followed the instructions written about how to ebbed the framework to my project.

My Project is written in `Objective-C` but the added framework is written in `Swift`.

After following all the mentioned steps i get many different (seems to be swift related error from an additional framework that i was asked to add called `Result.framework`)

And nothing compiles anymore of course.

Here are some errors printed in `Xcode`:

[image]

As i said, I followed all the [instructions](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa#getting-started) provided, all seem to work well.

Help anyone?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Swift code you are trying to integrate was written using outdated syntax.  Please see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html.  Look for a more recent version of the code.